# Flowise on Docker - PK errors when initializing database - Postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, flowise

I'm using Flowise 1.6.1 on Docker with a Postgres 16.2 database also on Docker.
When I run the Flowise container for the first time it starts but shows these errors regarding already existing PKs when initializing the database.
The database is newly created so it is completely empty before the initialization process.

Here are the errors:

```
2024-03-14 13:43:09 [INFO]: ⚡️ [server]: Flowise Server is listening at 3033
2024-03-14 13:43:09 [INFO]:  [server]: Data Source is being initialized!
Migration "AddFeedback1707213601923" failed, error: relation "PK_98419043dd704f54-9830ab78f8" already exists
2024-03-14 13:43:09 [ERROR]: ❌ [server]: Error during Data Source initialization: relation "PK_98419043dd704f54-9830ab78f8" already exists
QueryFailedError: relation "PK_98419043dd704f54-9830ab78f8" already exists
    at PostgresQueryRunner.query (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/flowise/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.js:219:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async AddFeedback1707213601923.up (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/flowise/dist/database/migrations/postgres/1707213601923-AddFeedback.js:6:9)
    at async MigrationExecutor.executePendingMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/flowise/node_modules/typeorm/migration/MigrationExecutor.js:225:17)
    at async DataSource.runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/flowise/node_modules/typeorm/data-source/DataSource.js:265:35)
    at async /usr/local/lib/node_modules/flowise/dist/index.js:77:13
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem with version 1.6.1 in the postgresql migration at this time.
Solution is to use a previous version.
I tried 1.6.0 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue on my end when updating docker container to latest version.

```html
024-03-14 18:35:45 [INFO]: ⚡️ [server]: Flowise Server is listening at 3000
2024-03-14 18:35:45 [INFO]:  [server]: Data Source is being initialized!
Migration "AddFeedback1707213601923" failed, error: relation "PK_98419043dd704f54-9830ab78f8" already exists
2024-03-14 18:35:45 [ERROR]: ❌ [server]: Error during Data Source initialization: relation "PK_98419043dd704f54-9830ab78f8" already exists
QueryFailedError: relation "PK_98419043dd704f54-9830ab78f8" already exists
    at PostgresQueryRunner.query (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/flowise/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.js:219:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async AddFeedback1707213601923.up (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/flowise/dist/database/migrations/postgres/1707213601923-AddFeedback.js:6:9)
    at async MigrationExecutor.executePendingMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/flowise/node_modules/typeorm/migration/MigrationExecutor.js:225:17)
    at async DataSource.runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/flowise/node_modules/typeorm/data-source/DataSource.js:265:35)
    at async /usr/local/lib/node_modules/flowise/dist/index.js:77:13
```

Comment: What version were you using succesfully on Docker?
I just installed it for the first time and the container available was the  1.61.
Same PK error... a bug perhaps? 
Thank you!

Comment: It should be a comment, not answer